# Error reading text file in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a file I need to import into a database. (My database is good, I can connect and I can add). Now my problem is for some reason nothing gets inserted.

I have a file **schooldatabase.txt** of users/password I need to add to a database. The file has 200 lines.

Here's a sample:

```
test|098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6
test2|ad0234829205b9033196ba818f7a872b
```

Now for each of these line (student username and password) I have to insert them in a database.

Here's my code:

```
function addUser($user,$pass) {
// this code is good
}

function processUser($user,$pass) {
  $pass=md5($pass);
  $myFile = "schooldatabase.txt";
  $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
  $theData = fread($fh, 5);
  $login = "$user|$pass";
  if(stristr($theData,$login) !== false){
      $result = "rejected";
  }
  elseif(stristr($theData,$login) !== true){
      addUser($user,$pass); // this work I manuall tested
      $result = "accepted";
   }
   fclose($fh);
   return $result;
}
var_dump(processUser('invaliduser','test2'));
```

Why it return "accepted" if that user is not in the file?

Comment: What exactly are you attempting to use the `schooldatabase.txt` file for? Also, I doubt you only want to read 5 bytes at a time (see [`fread()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php))

Comment: stristr will never return TRUE. Infact, stristr returns the matched substring or FALSE if needle is not found.

Comment: How big is the file schooldatabase.txt?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think here you should re-think about your process. I assume you "processUser" more than one time therefore you will open/read/close the same file over and over without altering that file.

Because the file is not huge (and I assume it's a one-time-script), Just open the file in memory when you start your script then you can compare all the value you are testing with that file.

You can use the function [file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) to do so. Then you can check if the user exists using [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

Here's the script:

```
function addUser($user,$pass) {
// this code is good
}

$file = file("schooldatabase.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES ^ FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

function processUser($user,$pass, array &$file) {
  $pass = md5($pass);
  if(in_array("$user|$pass", $file)) {
    addUser($user,$pass); // do you check if the query is good?
    return 'accepted';
  } 
  return "rejected";
}

var_dump(processUser('invaliduser','test2', $file));
```

Comment: i had to change code and the FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES ^ FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES was the solution to my new code thanks

Answer (score 20):

I think you're overcomplicating the `if` a bit -- it's either true or false, so no need to check that `stristr` twice!  Also, you might have your true/false mixed up.

Edit: Also, it should probably be stripos, which will return the position or false.

Try...

```
if(stripos($theData,$login) === false){
    $result = "rejected";
} else {
    addUser($user,$pass); // this work I manuall tested
    $result = "accepted";
}
```

...does that work?

Comment: Just made a change (thanks to @AurelioDeRosa) so you might want to update it! Also, what @Phil says should be checked, increase your fread length.